# Using pickadate.js with a standard rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pickadate

I'm trying to add pickadate.js to my project for the first time. I'm hitting some snags with trying to get the functionality working. Here is what I'm currently working with.

### Datepicker.js

```
var $input = $('.start-datepicker').pickadate()

var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')

picker.open()
```

### Form.html.erb

```
<div>
   <%= form.text_field :start_at, class: "new-assignment-form__input start-datepicker", placeholder: "Start Time" %>
</div>
```

That basically it. The action I'm going for is if a user tries to use that field it will pop open the date picker. It seemed from the docs that this is all that was needed but clearly I'm missing something because nothing happens with the current setup. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any output in the browser logs?

Comment: Yeah.. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: What happens if you put a `console.log($input);` statement directly after you define `$input`. What is printed out?

Comment: `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".start-datepicker"]`

Comment: Okay, can you call the `.length` method on the `$input` and let me know what it says?

Comment: It just says `0`

Comment: Okay we're getting somewhere. Could you type this and let me know what happens: `console.log($('.start-datepicker').length);`

Comment: Still getting a `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay based on our discussion, it looks like this selector:

```
$('.start-datepicker')
```

is not selecting anything. Double check to make sure that you have an element defined with a class of "start-datepicker".

Comment: I do. its in the form input.

Comment: If you had it defined, then typing `$('.start-datepicker').length` would return `1`

Comment: Hmm. Very strange... Thanks for the help!